# Indenting C with brace macros

Tags: indentation, filetype-c

I use a bunch of weird C macros which basically should behave like braces as far as formatting is concerned. My `equalprg` is empty, so I'm using vim's indenting function for `=` formatting. Is there any way I can tell vim about these macros, so they're indented appropriately?

Example: functions a and b should be formatted the same with the `=` command:

```
void a(void){
    $begin
    foo();
        bar();
    baz();
    $end
}

void a(void){
    {
        foo();
    bar();
    baz();
    }
}
```

Comment: I suppose you are using `cindent` (What is the result of `:set cindent?`). If so it is probably possible but depending how much you are relying the feature of `cindent` it could become a lot of work. You would have to depend on `indentexpr` that need to be written for your case.

Comment: @VivianDeSmedt Thanks. It's `cindent`. Haven't explored these options much yet.

Comment: The `cindent` mode is configurable but probably not supporting what you want. If not then the solution would be to develop (or reuse) an `indentexpr` and add the functionality you want :-) The code of `GetJavaIndent()` could be a start.